# No puedo enviar 2 valores por medio de ajax problemas con mi ruta

Tags: laravel, ajax, modal

Estoy tratando de editar datos en un modal para no estar recargando la pagina pero no se como podría mandarle los datos a través de jquery.

Lo intente de esta forma pero no se como podria mandarle o indicarle que me tome los 2 parametros que son id_enlace y periodo para que me identifique un registro y me mande esos datos a mi modal para luego poder editarlos pero no se como puedo realizarlo estos son mis 2 valores que quiero capturar en mi ajax pero no se como      {{$datos->id_enlace}}  y {{ ($datos->periodo)}}  para poder ir al controlador y hacer la consulta para que me traiga los datos que quiero y poderlos mostrar en el modal

este es mi datatables con los datos

```
    <div class="box" align="center">

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="content">
                <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                        <th>DESC_ENLACE</th>
                        <th>NO_FACTURA</th>
                        <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                        <th>VALOR_PAGO</th>
                        <th>PERIODO</th>
                        <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                        <th>OPCIONES</th>
                        <th>OPCIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($datos as $datos)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datos->desc_enlace}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datos->no_factura}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datos->valor_pago}}</td>
                            <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->periodo)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                            <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->fecha_factura)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>

                            <td>
                                <button type="button" href="{{ route('datos_modal',$datos->id_enlace.'/'.$datos->periodo)}}" class="btn btn-primary"  id="myModall" href="#updateUser" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a  href="{{url('eliminar/'.$datos->id_enlace.'/'.$datos->periodo)}}"  class="btn btn-danger active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Eliminar</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Este es mi ajax donde quiero recibir mis 2 variables que son id_enlace y periodo pero no se en el boton datatables como puedo hacer para que me envie esos datos aqui para luego hacer la consulta en mi controlador

```
         <script>
    $(document).on("click","#myModall", function(){

        var loc = $(this).attr('href');
        var date= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:loc,
            data: date,
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('todo bien');
            },
            error : function(xhr, status) {
                console.log(status);
                alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
            },
        })
    })
</script>
```

Esta es mi ruta para hacer la consulta

```
Route::GET('datos_modal',[
    'as'=>'datos_modal',
    'uses'=>'vista@modal'
]);
```

este es mi controlador donde mando los dos datos capturados para obtener los datos de quiero para luego retornar los valores obtenidos y mandarlos a mi vista donde tengo el modal

```
 public function modal($id_enlace,$periodo)
{
    $modal = importar::select('proveedor', 'desc_enlace', 'no_factura', 'id_enlace', 'valor_pago', 'periodo', 'fecha_factura', 'fecha_ingreso')
        ->where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)->where('PERIODO', $periodo)->get();

    return back()->with('message')->with(
        [
            'modal' => $modal
        ]
    );
}
```

este es mi modal en el cual quiero mostrar los datos que obtengo en el controlador pero no se como hacerlo

```
  @foreach($modal as $modal)
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <center><h4 class="modal-title">Editar_Cliente</h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputEmail4">Proveedor</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $modal->proveedor}}"id="inputEmail4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputPassword4">Id_enlace</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{$modal->id_enlace}}"  id="inputPassword4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputAddress">Desc_enlace</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{$modal->desc_enlace}}"id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputAddress2">Valor_pago</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" value="{{$modal->valor_pago}}"placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputCity">Periodo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{$modal->periodo}}"id="inputCity">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputCity">Fecha Factura</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{$modal->fecha_factura}}"id="inputCity">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <center><button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button></center>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Me estoy yendo y no llego a poner una respuesta, hice exactamente eso que decis para un sistema en el que estoy trabajando, no quisiera dejarte un copy paste de lo mio porque entiendo que no serviria como respuesta. Lo que hice fue lo siguiente: El boton editar tiene una clase y un atributo id que se le carga a cada uno para identificarlo de los demas botones de editar, al clickear se dispara en javascript una llamada a ajax. En ajax recibo el id y voy al controlador a ejecutar el metodo Recuperar, para traer los datos del elemento a editar, y los guardo en una respuesta.

Comment: Devuelvo esta respuesta de manera tal que la reciba la llamada ajax que cree en el javascript, y en el success del ajax pones lineas del tipo $("#nombreUsuario").val(respuesta["usuario"]; y de esa manera se llenan en tiempo real con datos de la base, sin necesidad de refrescar. Espero haber sido claro

Comment: bueno no tan claro seria mejor si me lo tratas de adaptar a mi respuesta para tener una idea mas clara

Comment: edite mi respuesta para ver si es asi como me lo indicas

Comment: ahora estoy trabajando, a la noche cuando vuelvo a mi casa, si nadie te facilito una respuesta te armo una. Suerte

Comment: ahi lo edite ahora si me funciona el problema que tengo ahora es que no puedo solo mandarle el identificador id_enlace ya que tengo que enviarle 2 parametros lo que es id_enlace y periodo para que identifique un unico registro

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer uso de ajax, para enviar datos en segundo plano. atravez de post

```
$(document).on("click",".btnmodal", function(){//estoy diciendo que cuando haga click en el boton que habre el modal entonces va hacer lo siguiente...
    var id1 = $('#id_enlace').val();//estamos capturando el valor

     var id2 = $('#id_perido').val();//estamos capturando el valor

     var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("id1", id1);

        datos.append("id2", id2);

        $.ajax({

            url:"ajax/nombre_donde_recibiras_los_valores.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(respuesta){

                //puedes retornar una repuesta desde tu archivo ajax/nombre_donde_recibiras_los_valores.ajax.php

            }
        })
})
```

y desde tu archivo ajax/nombre_donde_recibiras_los_valores.ajax.php,

capturarias tus valores asi.

> $_POST[id1]; $_POST[id2];

ejemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST["id1"])){
//entonces haga tal cosas
}
```

Comment: Ahi lo edite tratando de adaptarlo a mi codigo para que lo revises a ver si va asi

Comment: Aunque técnicamente funcional, así no es la forma de recibir valores en Laravel, no sigue parte de sus buenas prácticas; checa sobre `Request`, ademas la URL tampoco lleva extensión .php puesto que se llama por medio del nombre que le diste a la url

Comment: bueno es que tengo problemas para capturar las 2 variables que necesito para realizar mi consulta en mi controlador no se como pasarle   <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td> y periodo  a mi ajax para que me mande los datos no se como hacerlo y que la url que le indico me lleve a mi controlador el nombre que le coloco ahi es el de mi ruta para que me lleve al controlador